# Implement @emotion/babel-plugin with jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babeljs, gatsby, emotion

In our project we got the `@emotion/babel-plugin` working, but we just can't get it to work with jest, our `jest-preprocess` file looks like the following:

```
const babelJest = require('babel-jest');

const babelOptions = {
  presets: ['babel-preset-gatsby'],
  plugins: ['@emotion'],
};

module.exports = babelJest.default.createTransformer(babelOptions);
```

When we run the tests we just get:

```
Component selectors can only be used in conjunction with @emotion/babel-plugin.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```
// jest-preprocess.js
const babelJest = require('babel-jest').default;

const babelOptions = {
  presets: [
    "babel-preset-gatsby",
    "@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop",
  ],
  plugins: ["emotion"],
}
module.exports = babelJest.createTransformer(babelOptions)
```